# JavaFX 2.2 MediaPlayer: how to release media file handle on Windows

Tags: swt, eclipse-rcp, javafx-2

I'm using JavaFX in an editor of an Eclipse RCP application to play video's. During initialization of the editor UI, I do something along the lines:

```
canvas = new FXCanvas(imageSection, SWT.NONE);
canvas.setScene(createScene());
...
// createScene()
Media media = new Media(file.toURI().toString());
MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer(media);
MediaView view = new MediaView(player);
...
player.play();
```

In the editor's dispose method, I make sure the video stops playing:

```
@Override
public void dispose() {
    player.stop();
    super.dispose();
}
```

However, If I want to delete the video resource that was playing in the editor after the editor is closed (both from my own application or from windows explorer), the file cannot be deleted because it is still in use by my application. It appears fx's Media object never released the video resource. I cannot find any pointer in the javafx documentation to ask the Media or MediaPlayer object to release the resource when the editor is closed.

My question: how can I make sure javafx releases the video file upon the editor closing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For what it is worth, I posted my question on the JavaFX forum. In response, I was pointed to the this Jira ticket:  http://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-18224

The suggestion in the ticket didn't help my situation, so I am stuck with my work-around.

Comment: I tried this as well and it didn't work for me neither. It's for sure a bug in the javafx code, failing to release the inputstream or something. Furthermore, as stated in the comments of the jira issue, there should be explicit api for this.

Answer (score 2):

Just had the same issue and after lots of reading I found this post (https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8123986). One of the lasts advice is to simply use **dispose()** on the **MediaPlayer** object which worked fine for me.

If you need to make sure to release the file after the audio is played you can do something like this:

```
File recording = new File("recording.mp3");
Media media = new Media(recording.toURI().toString());
final MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(media);
mediaPlayer.play();
mediaPlayer.setOnEndOfMedia(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        mediaPlayer.dispose();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have run into the same (or similar) problem. In my case, I am using JavaFX MediaPlayer inside a stand-along Java Swing desktop application. I am using JRE 1.7.0_10 and JavaFx 2.2.4-b18. The application is run on a Windows machine. In my case, there are situations where some of the media files need to be deleted after they have been played. I happen to be using the Files.delete() method. It always throws IOException with the message 'The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process', but does so on only the last file played. Before attempting the delete, I am making sure to call stop() on the media player.

I have also recreated this scenario in the PlayingAudio example (Chapter 3-1) in Carl Dea's book 'JavaFX 2.0 Introduction by Example', by modifying the said example to call delete() on the media's File object in the stop button's event handler. Again, I am making sure to call delete after stopping the media player. (This example is purely JavaFX, no Swing.)

For what it is worth, the way I worked around this in my Swing application was to call deleteOnExit() on any File that threw the IOException I mentioned earlier. And even then I had to make sure that while exiting the application I first called Platform.exit(), without which the deleteOnExit() didn't work either.

I hope this is of some help.

Answer (score 0):

If we load many files in the application and calling seek() by using slider, as the no of files encreases the performanance of the application drops accordinlgy and the memory graph of the OS shows the encresing ratio of the memory.Looks loke JavaFx memory leak in media issue.
Now, there is another Bug : https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-28379